# Use function return in if statement or variable in go template

Tags: function, templates, go

I'm using a go template to filter out improperly named services with consul-template. I am provided a function regexMatch from consul-template that works like this:

```
{{"foo.bar" | regexMatch "foo([.a-z]+)"}}
```

It returns true or false depending on the string. I'd like to use this conditionally in an if statement, similar to other code I have that filters out services with the name "consul". That works like this:

```
{{range services}} {{$service:=.Name}} {{if not (eq $service "consul")}}
```

The problem is that I can't nest the function call inside that if statement or a variable declaration. I have tried

```
{{if {$service | regexMatch "^[-a-z0-9]{1,}$"}}}}
```

and

```
{{$syntax= {$service | regexMatch "^[-a-z0-9]{1,}$"}}}}
```

but I get these errors:

```
unexpected "{" in if
unexpected bad character U+003D '='
```

How can I use the regexMatch function in an if statement in this go template?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone ever needs it,

```
{{if $service | regexMatch "^[-a-z0-9]{1,}$"}}
```

from https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/.

specifically:

{{pipeline}}
    The default textual representation of the value of the pipeline
    is copied to the output.

{{if pipeline}} T1 {{end}}
    If the value of the pipeline is empty, no output is generated;
    otherwise, T1 is executed.  The empty values are false, 0, any
    nil pointer or interface value, and any array, slice, map, or
    string of length zero.
    Dot is unaffected.